# GIT: Update to upstream loses all local changes not in upstream

Tags: git

I'm trying to update my local repo to match the upstream. There are a bunch of conflicts. How do I lose my local changes when updating?

Comment: That's easy: `git merge -s theirs`. It becomes complicated when you want to keep them...

Comment: in addition if your changes does not conflict I suggest to use git pull --rebase upstream master that will move your commits on top after upstream ones

Comment: My code conflicts. I want to loose my conflicting code. I want my local to be exactly what upstream is. When I did git merge -s I got conflict messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my local to be exactly what upstream is

This is a "hard reset". All changes in your local branch are lost.

```
git checkout master

git reset --hard my_upstream_branch_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b newbranchname
```

Then move back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

Then try pull and merge (something like)

```
git pull upstream master
```

You can also take an old commit, and merge upstream with that to ensure a fast forward merge. Then you can try to slowly solve the conflicts.

If you want to try solving it one file at a time, try:

```
git checkout newbranchname
git merge master
```

If there are conflicts, it will merge only in the working directory. Now you can solve conflicts in a single file.

Then you can try:

```
git reset
```

Which unstages all changes, and add the file you solved conflicts for:

```
git add solvedfile
git commit -m "Single file merged"
```

If you solve another file, you can

```
git add anotherfile
git commit --amend -m "2 files merged"
```

The --amend amends the previous commits, so that you see a single commit with both changes.

Comment: I get a bunch of conflicts. Is there a way to tell git to get rid of old code and just give me upstream's code?